# Max characters then start text scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

```
----------------------------------------------------
| This is my text inside a div and I want the scroll|ing of the text to start
----------------------------------------------------
```

If you go over the max characters it will automatic scroll and keep on scrolling till you delete some text after the max characters.

```
----------------------------------------------------
| This is my text inside a div and I want the scroll|
----------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas how can this be done?

I believe it maybe jquery and css, but not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9y8bB/)**

CSS:

```
 div.box {
     width:400px;
     height:40px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     position:relative;
 }
 .content {
     white-space: nowrap;
     width:350px;
     overflow: auto;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
</div>
```

For marquee: i hope this link will help you **[LINK](http://javascript.about.com/library/blctmarquee1.htm)**

Comment: This wont produce a scrollbar, the text will simply wrap into more than one line, it will also not automatically scroll

Answer (score 2):

I've provided both fixed and marquee solutions below.

It is important to add `white-space:nowrap;` to ensure a single line of text is enforced, otherwise it will break and not produce a scrollbar.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/XxUXD/1182/)

HTML

```
<p class="fixed">text text text text text</p>
<p class="marquee">text text text text text</p>
```

CSS

```
.fixed{
    width:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    word-wrap:normal;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.marquee {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 4s linear infinite;
}
.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        text-indent: 27.5em
    }
    100% {
        text-indent: -10em
    }
}
```

Comment: That kinda what I want to happen if it goes over the max width over the div box, overflow is perfect but I want it to scroll automatic once it overflowing.